# different APT messages for 'install' and 'autoremove' VS 'upgrade'

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I had to make some upgrades and after that I got to puzzling situation - executing APT commands 'autoremove' or 'install' says that "3 not upgraded" (packages) but executing 'upgrade' says "0 not upgraded".

What could cause this conflicting message?
How to find those 3 packages which are "not upgraded" but not visible to upgrade?
How to make 'upgrade' command to see it and upgrade?

Below is copy-paste from terminal:

```
aytvill@host:~$ sudo apt autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
aytvill@host:~$ sudo apt install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
aytvill@host:~$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```